# How to stop a timer in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I have a timer which i am using in my application..

In my application ,I have two views. On the first view i have added a button and a progress bar and i have used a timer for progress bar.

User can move to next view either on clicking the button or wait for progress bar to complete..

If the progress bar is completed the user will be drawn to next view..

Here, is my question How to stop timer which have no name like...

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0005 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Because of not stopping the timer in the first view if the user waits for progress bar to complete,the things in the next view will not work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the returned `NSTimer` from `scheduledWithTimeInterval:::::` and later call `invalidate` on it to stop the timer.

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0005 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

// This will stop the tmer
[timer invalidate];
```

Answer (score 1):

To stop timer you need to use 
[timer invalidate];